# Переключение timepicker между счетчиком и часами программно

Tags: java, android, время

Возможно ли сделать такой переключатель с часов на счетчик, как на картинках?

[image: digital clock]

[image: spinner]

Comment: Ну а что вас смущает? Можно.

Comment: `TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.myPicker, (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, minute, true);` Я пытаюсь создать timePicker следующим образом, в нем нет такой кнопки слева снизу, как в примере :(

Comment: TimePickerDialog разный для версий Андроида, вы при желании можете создать свой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На скринах в вашем вопросе [стандартный TimePicker из версии Android 8 Oreo](https://www.androidpolice.com/2017/03/23/android-o-feature-spotlight-time-picker-now-manual-text-entry-mode/). Насколько я в курсе, в версиях Android 9 и 10 используется такой же.
Соответственно такой диалог будет появляться у всех пользователей версий Android 8, 9, 10 (не уверен насчёт всяких MIUI) без дополнительных действий с вашей стороны.
Если вам нужен такой диалог для всех версий андроид, то можно поискать библиотеку или попытаться стащить этот класс из исходников Oreo или выше.